# Can anyone tell me, how to get state-country picklist values metadata api?

Tags: api

I need to fetch dependent pick list values of state and country. I want every state corresponding to the country, Please tell me how to achieve it using api or apex code, Which ever is possible.

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve the [AddressSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_addresssettings.htm) to get the values and migrate them.

In SFDX:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Settings:Address
```

And in the metadata API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <version>46.0</version>
    <types>
        <members>Address</members>
        <name>Settings</name>
    </types>
</Package>
```

Run this package.xml in the Ant Metadata Toolkit, or request the metadata via the API directly if you're using the WSDL.

There is not a direct version of this you can access in Apex, unfortunately.

Comment: This is very good solution that does not use any other resources, however, you are wrong and it can be done through apex using MetadataService.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova sfdxfox meant natively in Apex like `Standard Apex Metadata API` , apex-mdapi is custom and comes with steep learning curve

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to be done through apex class with help of MetadataService (https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls).

Here is the code example:

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
service.CallOptions = new MetadataService.CallOptions_element();
service.timeout_x = 120000;

List<MetadataService.AddressSettings> ans = new List<MetadataService.AddressSettings>();

ans.addAll((List<MetadataService.AddressSettings>) service.readMetadata('AddressSettings', new List<String>{
        'Address'
}).getRecords());

MetadataService.AddressSettings addressSettings = ans[0];

for (MetadataService.Country country_i : addressSettings.countriesAndStates.countries) {
    system.debug(country_i.label + ' ' + country_i.isoCode);
    if (country_i.states != null && country_i.states.size() > 0) {
        List<String> states = new List<String>();
        for (MetadataService.State state_i : country_i.states) {
            states.add(state_i.label + ' ' + state_i.isoCode);
        }
        system.debug(String.join(states, ', '));
    } else {
        system.debug('-');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution & provides exact what we want.